# How can I avoid indexError using list comprehension in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have an array of dictionaries and I want to check if a particular key is in the array of dicts and retrieve the item.
I know how to do this using list comprehension but is there a way to avoid indexError without doing this?

```
result = [x[fruit]["weight"] for x in [{"apple":{"weight":0.25}},{"orange":{"weight":0.25}}] if fruit in x.keys()]
if result:
   weight_of_fruit = result[0]
```

I'd rather do this:

```
result = [x[fruit]["weight"] for x in [{"apple":{"weight":0.25}},{"orange":{"weight":0.25}}] if fruit in x.keys()][0]
```

But this has a risk of indexError.

Is there something I can do with an array that is like a dict .get() method? So I can write this in a clean line of code.

Comment: And what would be the value of result if the list was empty?

Comment: Why must you do it like that? It is barely readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next()` with default value:

```py
lst = [{"apple": {"weight": 0.25}}, {"orange": {"weight": 0.25}}]

fruit = "pear"
result = next((d[fruit]["weight"] for d in lst if fruit in d), [])

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I still think it's ugly and unreadable but if you REALLY MUST, use

```
fruit = 'unknown'
result = [x[fruit]["weight"] if fruit in x.keys() else None for x in [{"apple":{"weight":0.25}},{"orange":{"weight":0.25}}]][0]
```

Keep in mind that I've changed the order of `if fruit in x.keys()` and added `else None`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using conditional with `.get()`

`next()` : is used to iterate through the list of dictionaries.

**code:**

```
fruit = "apple"
data = [{"apple": {"weight": 0.25}}, {"orange": {"weight": 0.25}}]

weight_of_fruit = next((x.get(fruit, {}).get("weight", None) for x in data), None)
print(weight_of_fruit)
```

**output:**

```
0.25
```

**Explanation:**
This code finds the weight of the specified fruit in the list of dictionaries and if the fruit is not found then returns `None`.